# Rotate Camera when touch unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

Here it is. I have a human anatomy, and I would like to rotate the camera when I touch anywhere. but looking at the human anatomy. how can I do that :(

[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EfYeL2FYyyA&t=148s] this is what exactly I really wanted to please help me !

```
 `

    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    [AddComponentMenu("Camera-Control/Mouse Orbit with zoom")]
   public class MouseOrbitImproved : MonoBehaviour {
public Transform target;
public float distance = 5.0f;
public float xSpeed = 120.0f;
public float ySpeed = 120.0f;

public float yMinLimit = -20f;
public float yMaxLimit = 80f;
public float distanceMin = .5f;
public float distanceMax = 15f;
private Rigidbody rigidbody;
float x = 0.0f;
float y = 0.0f;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    Vector3 angles = transform.eulerAngles;
    x = angles.y;
    y = angles.x;  rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    // Make the rigid body not change rotation
    if (rigidbody != null)
    {
        rigidbody.freezeRotation = true;
    }
}
void LateUpdate () 
{
    if (target) 
    {
        x += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * xSpeed * distance * 0.02f;
        y -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * ySpeed * 0.02f;
        y = ClampAngle(y, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(y, x, 0);
        distance = Mathf.Clamp(distance - Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel")*5, distanceMin, distanceMax);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Linecast (target.position, transform.position, out hit)) 
        {
            distance -=  hit.distance;
        }
        Vector3 negDistance = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -distance);
        Vector3 position = rotation * negDistance + target.position;
        transform.rotation = rotation;
        transform.position = position;
    }
}
public static float ClampAngle(float angle, float min, float max)
{
    if (angle < -360F)
        angle += 360F;
    if (angle > 360F)
        angle -= 360F;
    return Mathf.Clamp(angle, min, max);
}}
```

Comment: Please take a look at [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), add code formatting, and specify what exact _programming_ problem you're trying to solve. E.g. "I try to make this framework do that and it should work according to this (link) documentation, but it does not".

Answer (score 1):

You could use a trick instead of using too many "math" in this case.

There will be empty gameObjects in each of the element you want your camera to rotate around, lets call those "anchors"

When the element is selected, you simply make the camera child of the anchor.

And then if you just rotate the anchor, your camera will rotate because it is the child.

This will get the effect you want.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S3pjBQObC90) is a simple example from youtube, for rotating the object.

[Here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/255118/rotating-an-object-with-touch.html) is another one from Unity answers.

Hope this helps! Cheers!

Comment: Thanks ! i'll try it